# Format the display of the GroupBy header for Xceed Grid

Tags: xaml, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I am using the groupby control on an xceed grid. I am trying to format the header. I want to get rid of the circled part in the pic below. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my binding on the FieldName to match what I needed.